# Как определить transform.position крайних вершин 2d объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Всем привет.

Делаю простенький генератор уровня для 2д платформера, где к концу одной платформы стыкуется начало другой , т.е. для размещения платформы я использую две точки, её начала и конца соответственно.

Платформа сделана так, что точка pivot является её началом, тоесть transform.position объекта и есть её начало, которая будет приравниваться к точке конца предыдущей платформы, таким нехитрым макаром и будет генерироваться уровень, и вот вопрос: как мне определить конечную точку платформы? Точка pivot используется как начальная, рассчитывать в ручную (к начальной точке прибавлять длину платформы) не вариант, ибо размер платформы и спрайты еще могут меняться и подгоняться, а создавать еще одну один объект в виде дочерней точки которая будет концом платформы слишком громоздко, нужно будет тогда каждый раз искать её, нужно автоматизировать этот процесс, чтобы при изменении размеров объекта посредством кода автоматически искались крайние точки платформы, чтобы к ним присоединять другие. 
Мб таким же способом будет корректней определять начальную точку.

Где то давно видел, что каким то образом обращались к компоненту боксколлайдер2д и брали его крайнию вершину, только как это было точно не помню, в документации юнити не нашел примерно похожих нужных мне функций(есть к примеру функция center которая определяет собственно центр, но мне нужно определить например крайнюю левую, или правую верхнюю точку, как это например в спрайт эдиторе когда он автоматически определяет где разместить pivot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать как компонент [Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html), так и все унаследованное от [Collider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-bounds.html), чтобы у них посмотреть свойство `Bounds`, которое представляет собой границы объекта (прямоугольник вашего объекта на сцене).
А у Bounds (cм [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html)), есть min и max - вектора. С помощью них вы можете например получить любую точку прямоугольника, например нижний левый угол - `(Renderer.bounds.min.x, Renderer.bounds.min.y)`, а верхняя правая - `(Renderer.bounds.max.x, Renderer.bounds.max.y)`

Comment: А как получить верхний центр? нижний центр?